# Windows 10 internet connection eventually fails when Hyper-V VM running

Tags: windows-10, networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, hyper-v

I've got a VM running Ubuntu 22.04 running under Hyper-V in Windows 10.  The VM is sharing two internal drives which are formatted as ext4 using SAMBA and the Windows 10 host has them mapped as shared drives.  Everything works fine for a while (both host and VM can access the internet), anywhere from half an hour to a couple of days.  The first sign of trouble is that I notice that my Wifi connection icon has a bar over it and indicates that there is no Internet.  However, I often still have Internet access at this point and don't notice this, although at some point the internet starts to become unreliable (some sites work, some don't, connectivity comes and goes) and eventually fails altogether.  The Windows troubleshooter isn't able to fix the problem.

If I pause the VM, in less than a minute the internet is working again.  If I then resume the VM, sometimes the internet goes right back out, while sometimes it is spotty for a while and then either clears up or stops working again.  If it stops working again I usually have to reboot in order to get the internet back, which can be rather inconvenient when I have an uninterruptable task that is using the shared drives in the VM.  I usually do not have any issues with the host and the VM being able to talk to each other.

Configuration:
There are three drives under "SCSI Controller" all as "Physical hard disk".  One is the Ubuntu boot drive and the other two are data drives.

There is a network adapter which is a "Virtual Switch" with hardware acceleration "Enable virtual machine queue" and "Enable IPSec task offloading" maximum number "512".  A static MAC address is in use, and nothing else is checked under Advanced Features.  The virtual switch is connected to the "External Network" via the wireless adapter with "Allow management operating system to share this network adapter" checked.  The only virtual switch extension that is enabled is "Microsoft NDIS Capture".

Update: When Internet access has failed for the Windows 10 host I can still see the Internet from the VM.

Also, rebooting the VM works almost as well as rebooting Windows to make the problem go away.  I say *almost* because it seems like after the VM comes back up there is some lag from time to time in Windows, e.g. I will try to bring up a web page and it will sit for several seconds before anything happens.

Update 2: I tried disabling IPv6 and so far the Internet connection no longer fails.  However, now I have a new, more troubling issue in that my connection to the shared drive in the VM is unreliable, periodically being inaccessible when I'm in the middle of trying to access files on the drive causing all sorts of things to fail or go off the rails.

Update 3: Ok, I *thought* I disabled IPv6 on the Windows side by unchecking IPv6 for the virtual adapter.  But when I run the proper incantation of `get-vm` from an admin powershell I see that the VM has both an IPv4 *and* an IPv6 address assigned to it.  How do I stop it from getting an IPv6 address???

Comment: I assume internet connectivity is lost within the VM also, you don't specifically mention, if that is the case.  What do you mean you don't normally have an issue communicating with the host to the SAMBA server?

Comment: @Ramhound Actually, I was going to check that the next time it happened but this morning Windows was all ready to install updates and I forgot.  For the second part, what I mean is, Ubuntu in the VM is happily serving files to the Windows 10 host, even after internet connectivity is lost.

Comment: Are you using a WAN or LAN adapter?  Have you verified you are running the current version of the driver?

Comment: @Ramhound It's a LAN adapter, Qualcomm QCA61x4A (802.11ac). Windows claims "the best drivers" are already installed.

Comment: 802.11ac is considered to be a WAN adapter not LAN adapter

Comment: @Ramhound Oh.  I thought WAN referred to anything beyond the range of a LAN such as cell modems...

Comment: @Ramhound Huh. the [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_802.11ac-2013) claims 802.11ac is wireless LAN (WLAN) not WAN.

Comment: Ok, well let’s call that a typo on my part